# try to generating signature using HMACSHA512 in c#

Tags: javascript, java, c#

signature in c# using HMACSHA512 not equivalent to java and JavaScript.
after tracing my c# code i found the key is not used during generating signature.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

using System.Text;

string privateKey = "OPAYPRV16388855997950.6319778282304234";

string message = "{\r\n  \"country\": \"EG\",\r\n  \"reference\": \"9cf357a79ffc4cb5a57cd0489a1a4bfa\"\r\n}";

byte[] messagebyte = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message);
byte[] pkey =   Encoding.Default.GetBytes(privateKey);

HMACSHA512 hMACSHA512 = new HMACSHA512(pkey);

//hMACSHA512.Key = pkey; //other way and not give right signature

//hmacsha512.Initialize();

var hmac = hMACSHA512.ComputeHash(messagebyte);
var hmacres = BitConverter.ToString(hmac).Replace("-", "");

Console.WriteLine(hmacres);

// signature c# =FC96AABB47DE439A78CB98943BA3E9F9C25B24264E1431CC4180348F5B48C869F9003E3B67B8E387D25A7189093ACDD90205A103A489856379971EBE07E295E5

// signature in java and JavaScript (the same and the right signature)=
20c8b06951a7907b48db0ccb0b1fb514e8addb2b7c72786cc21316576d57e57560188cac837ffe232a9b24e65e73c6c05e6a5dddff3cc03e26521c92e74e064d
```

Comment: Check Encodings. Using "Default" encoding is not preferable to a specific one, if you actually _need_ a specific one. I.e. the same that Java / JS use.

Comment: i  used all encoding types ,the problem not with encoding.
the key is not used , result is the same whether i use key or not

Comment: Even if it's not, you should use _the_ specific encoding that java and js are using. What do you mean by "result is the same whether I use key or not"? How do you _not_ use the key?

Comment: i mean if i write object like this 
HMACSHA512 hMACSHA512 = new HMACSHA512();
signature not changed 
// signature c# FC96AABB47DE439A78CB98943BA3E9F9C25B24264E1431CC4180348F5B48C869F9003E3B67B8E387D25A7189093ACDD90205A103A489856379971EBE07E295E5

Comment: From [HMACSHA512(Byte[])](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha512.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-security-cryptography-hmacsha512-ctor(system-byte())) : _"If the key is more than 128 bytes long, it is hashed (using SHA-512) to derive a 128-byte key. If it is less than 128 bytes long, it is padded to 128 bytes."_ - did you verify you get the correct key as bytes?

Comment: pkey[38] ,length less than 128

Comment: Using `CryptoJS.HmacSHA512`, I got the same value in javascript (the one starting with FC96) that I got in C#. Might be worth posting your java/javascript code as well?

Comment: please try this code in javascript
<script type="text/javascript" >
const formData = {
"country":"EG",
"reference":"9cf357a79ffc4cb5a57cd0489a1a4bfa"
};

var privateKey = "OPAYPRV16388855997950.6319778282304234"
var body = JSON.stringify(formData);
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA512(body, privateKey).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
//var hash = sha512.hmac.create(privateKey+formData);
//hash.update(JSON.stringify(formData));
//hmacsignature = hash.hex();
console.log(hash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HMACSHA512 deal with `\r\n` and spaces as characters, when remove `/r/n` and space I got the right signature

```
message = message.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, string.Empty).Replace(" ", "");
byte[] messagebyte = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message);
byte[] pkey =   Encoding.Default.GetBytes(privateKey);
HMACSHA512 hMACSHA512 = new HMACSHA512(pkey);
var hmac = hMACSHA512.ComputeHash(messagebyte);
var hmacres = BitConverter.ToString(hmac).Replace("-", "");
```